# How can I restrict the Google Maps Places Library's Autocomplete to suggestions of only one city's places?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api

I am currently using the given code, but this only restricts suggestions to one country.
I have seen one implementation but its using jQuery and I want to do it without using jQuery.

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {
    //types: ['(cities)'],
    componentRestrictions: { country: 'pk' }
};
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete( input, options );
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try adding a `bounds` property to the `options` object you are passing to the `Autocomplete` constructor, as shown in this code:

```
var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng( 25.341233, 68.289986 );
var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng( 25.450715, 68.428345 );
var hyderabadBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds( southWest, northEast );

var options = {
    bounds: hyderabadBounds,
    types:  ['establishment [or whatever fits your usage]'],
    componentRestrictions: { country: 'pk' }
};
```

If you want the `Autocomplete` bounds to be driven by the current viewport of the map, you can bind the bounds of the map to the `Autocomplete` this way:

```
autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
```

Or, if it works better in your application, you also have the option to set the bounds explicitly whenever necessary:

```
autocomplete.setBounds( someOtherBounds );
```

This may mean that you create a default city, as I did with Hyberabad in the example above. Or that you allow your users to select from a list of cities to start and then set the map viewport to the selected city. The `Autocomplete` will suggest city names if you start out with just the `componentRestrictions` of `country 'PK'` as you are already doing. You will know what works best for your application.

Finally, this does not truly and completely restrict the `Autocomplete` to just the city, but it will achieve the result you wish as closely as currently possible.

Comment: http://hittheroad.ie/ allows autocomplete only in ireland and no other suggestions. how is this possible?

Comment: Sorry for this silly question, but how do I find the bounds for a specific city in a country?

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera: It's not silly, but you will get better results if you: open a new question, provide more detail about exactly what you are trying to achieve, include an example of your current code, and explain why that code is not working.

Comment: for the javascript sdk for autocomplete geo bounds is not working.can you point my error, or if this is depriciated autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            (document.getElementById('loc')), { types: ['geocode'], bounds: cityBounds, cities: [cc], componentRestrictions: { country: 'in', city: cc } });

Comment: @user3775217: I will be happy to take a look and try to help, but you should post a new question - adding a new item as a comment on an existing question isn't the way it works on stackoverflow. I'm not giving you a hard time; just trying to help you get the hang of how everything works.

Answer (score 2):

I found awesome examples of restricting or limiting search results by country using the Autocomplete class, i.e. there is a method called setComponentRestrictions which allows you to set the country (property), found here -https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#ComponentRestrictions

Please check out https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples-v3/source/browse/trunk/places/2012-may-hangout/autocomplete.html?r=290 for examples.

Answer (score 1):

For multiple country restrictions you can use

```
var options = {
    types: ['(cities)'],
    componentRestrictions: {
        country: ['de','at','ch']
    }
};
```