# Google Maps : Restrictions

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Would it be possible to restrict the autocomplete search results to certain provinces (states) within a country? I'm trying to limit my results to only that of Johannesburg (ZA) for example.

Answer (score 0):

There is pretty detailed response to your question on another stackoverflow thread:

[How can I restrict the Google Maps Places Library's Autocomplete to suggestions of only one city's places?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637183/how-can-i-restrict-the-google-maps-places-librarys-autocomplete-to-suggestions)

For now you can only filter using two letter country code or by working around this by using bounds.

There is a Feature Request to extend that:
http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4433

Star it if you would like to receive updates.