# Cannot get value from getPlace after place-auto-complete using coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-maps, coffeescript

I am a newbie on angularJs/coffeescript and is trying to integrate it with google maps.

Objective, is to get the place_id after auto-complete using getPlace() and store it somewhere safe by passing it on to a service method so that it can be saved used later.

Here is the code

coffeecode

```
class SomeController

constructor: (@$scope, @$log, @$location, @SomeService) ->

    @listing = {}


    getPlace: (place) ->
          place = @getPlace()
          alert(place.place_id)
          return place

    doSomethingMore: () ->

          @variable.whereGeo =  @getPlace().place_id
          alert(@listing.whereGeo)

    @SomeService.someFunction(@listing)  //save the place id somewhere 

controllersModule.controller('SomeController', SomeController)
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="SomeController as sc">

<div class="col-sm-3">
            <input places-auto-complete type="text" class="form-control" name="where" id="where" placeholder=""
                   ng-model="sc.search.where"  on-place-changed="sc.getPlace(place)">
        </div>

        <div ng-show= "sc.place.length">
            <p>Ideally something should Appear here after autocomplete </p>
            place_id = {{ sc.place }} <br/>

        </div>
<div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-2 col-xs-1 text-right">
                <button ng-click="sc.doSomethingMore()" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" id="btn_create">Submit</button>
            </div>
 </div>
```

Now the module used is **ngMap**. Here is the links
[angular-google-maps](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps)

Now let me add the details and the problem.

1. The autocomplete works fine
2. The getPlace function gets called
3. The alert is thrown with the place_id as expected. But , i dont
   get the data back in sc.place
4. On pressing submit , I get the error this.getPlace is
   undefined.

Things I have tried. I have used the fat arrow => in getPlace and got this.getPlace is undefined error and no alert is thrown on calling the getPlace either.

Tried looking up [here](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps) and [here](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/blob/master/testapp/places-auto-complete.html) and did the solution but didn't get it to work.
Also [this](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/issues/286) was useful to understand the scenario but didn't help

Any help regarding this is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. So I was doing it wrong. After some research  found this. I had got the scope all wrong. Explanation at the end.

Coffeescript

```
class SomeController

constructor: (@$scope, @$log, @$location, @SomeService) ->

@listing = {}
@place
    autocomplete_options = {
      types: ['geocode'] 
    }

    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('where'), autocomplete_options)

    google.maps.event.addListener autocomplete, 'place_changed', =>
        place = autocomplete.getPlace()
        console.log(place.place_id)
        @$scope.$apply =>
            @$scope.place = place.place_id




doSomethingMore: () ->

      @liating.whereGeo =  @$scope.place // now place id is available in scope 
      alert(@listing.whereGeo)

@SomeService.someFunction(@listing)  //save the place id somewhere 

controllersModule.controller('SomeController', SomeController)
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="SomeController as sc">

<div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="where" id="where" placeholder=""
                   ng-model="sc.search.where">
        </div>


<div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-2 col-xs-1 text-right">
                <button ng-click="sc.doSomethingMore()" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" id="btn_create">Submit</button>
            </div>
 </div>
```

Explanation

1. For what had to be achieved , the place_id had to be assigned to a
   global variable and then made available throughout scope.
2. The difference between => and -> in coffescript has to be kept in mind. I        found some good documentation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965855/coffeescript-when-to-use-fat-arrow-over-arrow-and-vice-versa)
3. Finally [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19186639/google-maps-places-javascript-api-autocompletion-restrict-types) answer was helpful